# Pentagonal Slitherlink Puzzles

Tags: slitherlink

[image]

Above are two Slitherlink puzzles on pentagonal boards. Enjoy, and let me know in the comments how difficult you think each puzzle is.

Comment: Left one has two solutions: https://i.imgur.com/jziFYEG.png

Comment: There are six solutions to the larger puzzle...

Comment: Each number is only associated with 3 edges, as opposed to regular 4. I wouldn’t call this a pentagonal board, more of a triangular board, seems to me.

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Answer (score 7):

Nice Puzzle... solved both (edit to merge solutions to clear clutter)

> [image]

Answer (score 7):

Multiple solutions to the larger  puzzle.

> [image]